# How can I make the results of a jquery json result make items visible

Tags: jquery, css

On my main page I have this jquery code which does an ajax call and loads the whole pages contents into a DIV on my page, it refreshes every X amount of seconds

```
<!-- Auto update/look for NEW notifications --> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     var updatenotification = function(){ 
          $('#notificationcontainer') 
               .load('/modules/member/home/notifications.inc.php') 
               .fadeIn("slow"); 
     }; 
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){updatenotification();}, 5000); 
     updatenotification(); 
}); 
</script> 
<!-- ENDS HERE -->


<div id="#notificationcontainer"></div>
```

I am wanting to change this though to make it send less data back and forth so I am wanting to make my notification.inc.php output a JSON string instead.
I will make it have these values;

item2 = 1

item5 = 1

notice there is 2 items that are marked with a 1, there is a total of 6 items but I will only include the ones in the json string that I need to show, on my main page I want to make a code that will read the json string 1 means that the jquery should make that item visible on the page
I will have all these items set to be hidden on the page, when 1 needs to be shown, jquery can just make it be visible.
Also the names are just generic they will all be changed

```
<style type="text/css">
#item1{
    display:none;
}
#item2{
    display:none;
}
#item3{
    display:none;
}
#item4{
    display:none;
}
#item5{
    display:none;
}
#item6{
    display:none;
}
</style>


<div id="notificationhead">Notifications</div>
<div class="notificationlink" id="item1"><a href="">Testing 1</a></div>
<div class="notificationlink" id="item2"><a href="">Testing 2</a></div>
<div class="notificationlink" id="item3"><a href="">Testing 3</a></div>
<div class="notificationlink" id="item4"><a href="">Testing 4</a></div>
<div class="notificationlink" id="item5"><a href="">Testing 5</a></div>
<div class="notificationlink" id="item6"><a href="">Testing 6</a></div>
```

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the solution to your question but another piece of advice. You could probably simplify things a bit by adding an additional class (like "visible") to the div you want to show, and setting the CSS to `display: block` on that and `display: none` to the the `notificationlink` class. Would eliminate the overhead of manually setting IDs on each div.

Multiple classes are allowed in HTML, so you can end up with anything like `class="notificationlink visible first-child extended"`. Perfectly valid.